# jQuery .each() and ajax to get size

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures, each

I have lists of addresses inside php files and the files are labelled by country. So in a list called uk I could have 12 list items of addresses. But on my homepage I am trying to use jQuery to calculate the values of each country and then put the value inside a div on that country map so that it indicates that uk was x addresses, usa has x addresses and so forth.

The code I have put together below works up till the .ajax and then in console.log it echos 1 single country instead of a list of countrys.

**HTML**

```
<div class="right map">
    <div class="canada" data-name="Canada"></div>
    <div class="usa" data-name="USA"></div>
    <div class="uk" data-name="UK"></div>
    <div class="ireland" data-name="Ireland"></div>
    <div class="spain" data-name="Spain"></div>
    <div class="portugal" data-name="Portugal"></div>
    <div class="italy" data-name="Italy"></div>
    <div class="australia" data-name="Australia"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.map div').each(function() { 
    $this = $(this);
    country = $this.attr("class");
    console.log(country);
    $.ajax({
        url : "/assets/inc/coe/"+country+".php",
            success : function (data) {
                console.log($('.map div.'+country));
                $('.map div.'+country).text($(data).find('li').size());
            }
        }); 
});
```

**php files**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <strong>Company Name</strong>
        123 Fake Street<br />
        Fakesville<br />
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>Company Name</strong>
        123 Fake Street<br />
        Fakesville<br />
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**console.log**

```
canada
usa
uk
ireland
spain
portugal
italy
australia
[div.australia]
[div.australia]
[div.australia]
[div.australia]
[div.australia]
[div.australia]
[div.australia]
[div.australia]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `country` is not in the scope of your `success` function. When your `success` function is invoked, it looks up the scope chain to find `country`. But because your AJAX runs asynchronously, the loop will always finish before `success` is invoked, and `country` will therefore *always* be the last country set in the loop.

To resolve this issue, you need to need to nest your `success` function in a new scope level and pass in `country` by value. In my example below, I accomplish that with an immediate executing function, that returns your original `success` function:

Change this:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "/assets/inc/coe/"+country+".php",
            success : function (data) {
                console.log($('.map div.'+country));
                $('.map div.'+country).text($(data).find('li').size());
            }
        });
```

To this:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "/assets/inc/coe/"+country+".php",
            success : (function (country) {
                return function(data) {
                    console.log($('.map div.'+country));
                    $('.map div.'+country).text($(data).find('li').size());
                };
            })(country)
        });
```

It's all about [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Answer (score 1):

Make your ajax request synchronous. Adding `async: false` will work. It will wait for the current ajax request to get finished before starting another. So the reference to `country` will correctly map to the correct country `div`

```
$('.map div').each(function() { 
$this = $(this);
country = $this.attr("class");
console.log(country);
$.ajax({
    url : "/assets/inc/coe/"+country+".php",
    async: false,
        success : function (data) {
            console.log($('.map div.'+country));
            $('.map div.'+country).text($(data).find('li').size());
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: @DonaldSutherland: While this solution should work, be aware that when setting `async: false` that your UI will lock-up during each individual request. If a request will then take a little while it can seem to the user like the browser is frozen.

Comment: @DonaldSutherland `Elliot B` answer would be better

Answer (score 0):

It's a closure problem and the asyncness of ajax; its got a handle on the country variable which beats all the ajax calls, so its always at the last setting (australia).

Write a new property to the ajax function/object

```
$.ajax({
        url : "/assets/inc/coe/"+country+".php",
        country: country,
            success : function (data) {
                var country = this.country;
                console.log($('.map div.'+country));
                $('.map div.'+country).text($(data).find('li').size());

            }
        });
```